# 404 error on POST Angular/ MVC application

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-mvc

I'm probably doing something dumb, but I can't for the life of me figure out why my route isn't working. Just trying to do a simple post request via a service which should be reaching the controller but it's not. Note the baseref is valid as it works and it looks like the URL should be correct in my browser window. Here's the code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Observer, BehaviorSubject, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DataService, ApiResponse, ApiResponseStatus } from './data.service';
import { CookieService } from './cookie.service'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BlogService extends DataService {

     constructor(cookieService: CookieService, http: HttpClient) {
          super(cookieService, http);
     }

     save(blob: any, authenticated: boolean): Observable<ApiResponse> {

          var operation = this.operationName();

          this.log([operation, blob, authenticated]);

          var url = `${this._apiBaseHref}v1/blog/save`

          return this.http.post<any>(url,
               {
               headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client-id': this._clientId, 'access-token': this._accessToken
               })
          });
     };
}
```

and then the controller - note I have a route prefix of  [RoutePrefix("v1/blog")] atop of the "blog" controller -

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpRoute("save")]
public JsonResponse Save()
{
    return new JsonResponse
    {
        Status = JsonResponseStatus.Success,
        Data = "data",
        Message = null
    };
}
```

here is a picture of the error I'm getting - [image]

thanks for any help in advanced for any help, it's very much appreciated... I'll provide whatever additional details are required to help get this figured out!

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable attribute routing, and MapMvcAttributeRoutes should be before MapRoute

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);

    //enable attribute routing     
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    //covention-based routes
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply Serge, I already have this under RouteConfig.cs, this is a client project, still no luck.